# C# Generic Type Function, Make Generic Method Fails with System.String

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm using .net Core 5.0.302 and having trouble using Reflection to invoke a generic method

The function is

```
public static T Parse<T>(List<Token> tokenList, int startPos) where T : new(){
            if(tokenList[startPos].tokenData.ToString() == "["){
                // ParseArray(tokenList);
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            else if(tokenList[startPos].tokenData.ToString() == "{"){
                return ParseObject<T>(tokenList, startPos);
            }else{
                T retVal = new T();
                retVal = (T)tokenList[startPos].tokenData;
                return retVal;
            }
        }
```

The code that is attempting to invoke this method is here -

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(JsonParser).GetMethod(nameof(JsonParser.Parse), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
                            method = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
                            object parsedType = method.Invoke(null, new object[]{tokenList, i + 3});
                            props[z].SetValue(typeInst, parsedType);
```

And this is the error message I'm receiving

> System.Security.VerificationException : Method ParseLib.JsonParser.Parse: type argument 'System.String' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.
> Stack Trace:
> at System.RuntimeType.ValidateGenericArguments(MemberInfo definition, RuntimeType[] genericArguments, Exception e)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type[] methodInstantiation)
> at ParseLib.JsonParser.ParseObject[T](List`1 tokenList, Int32 startPos) in /home/user/Projects/MyProjects/JsonParseSharp/ParseLib/JsonParser.cs:line 54 at ParseLib.JsonParser.Parse[T](List`1 tokenList, Int32 startPos) in /home/user/Projects/MyProjects/JsonParseSharp/ParseLib/JsonParser.cs:line 15
> at ParseTests.JsonParserTest.TestParseBasicObject() in /home/user/Projects/MyProjects/JsonParseSharp/ParseTests/JsonParserTest.cs:line 16
> ----- Inner Stack Trace -----
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.GetStubIfNeeded(RuntimeMethodHandleInternal method, RuntimeType declaringType, RuntimeType[] methodInstantiation)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type[] methodInstantiation)

Haven't been able to figure out why System.String violates the type parameter 'T' if I replace typeof(string) with typeof(int), everything works as expected. Does anyone have any idea what might be the issue here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `string` doesn't have a parameterless constructor. `: new(){`

Comment: Ah that would make sense...is there any way to add a parameterless constructor to string or if I need my generic function to be <string> I'll just have to go about handling that case a different way?

Comment: Yeah you will need some kind of different technique for strings, alas.

Comment: BTW, had you duplicated this by calling the function directly (i.e., not via reflection) as a test, you'd probably have gotten the same or similar error message. But, without the complication of reflection you probably could have figured it out. I write **a lot** of little test programs besidr the code I'm writing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where T : new()`

Your Parse method has a type constraint that indicates that type T must have a public parameterless constructor.

in c#, the string constructor requires at least one parameter to construct a string.

`var str = new string("abc")`

But the int can be instantiated using a parameterless constructor:

`var num = new int()`